# Huge loss in regression exercise! Testing with batch input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, batch-processing, linear-regression

I am currently running the following code in order to predict the price of a house based on 6 parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

housing = pd.read_csv('cal_housing_clean.csv')

X = housing.iloc[:,0:6]
y = housing.iloc[:,6:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.transform(X_train),columns = X_train.columns,index=X_train.index)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.transform(X_test),columns = X_test.columns,index=X_test.index)

X_data = tf.placeholder(dtype = "float", shape=[None,6])
y_target = tf.placeholder(dtype = "float", shape=[None,1])

hidden_layer_nodes = 10

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[6,hidden_layer_nodes]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[hidden_layer_nodes]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[hidden_layer_nodes,1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))

hidden_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X_data,w1),b1))
y_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_output,w2),b2)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_target-y_output))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.00001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

steps = 100000

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(steps):

        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X_data:X_train,y_target:y_train})

        if i%500 == 0:

            print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))

            training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_data:X_test,y_target:y_test})
            print("Training cost=", training_cost/6192)

    training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_data:X_test,y_target:y_test})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost/6192)
```

I hereby thought that since the test_set contains 6192 rows of data, that simply dividing the total loss or error by that value would solve the problem, but unfortunately I reach the following output:

```
Currently on step 0
Training cost= 9190063.95866
Currently on step 500
Training cost= 9062077.85013
Currently on step 1000
Training cost= 8927415.89664
Currently on step 1500
Training cost= 8795428.38243
Currently on step 2000
Training cost= 8666037.25065
Currently on step 2500
Training cost= 8539182.30491
Currently on step 3000
Training cost= 8414841.71576
```

in which the error will go down to about 2 Million while I would like to have values close to 100 or 200 thousand.

Maybe there is an error in my code that makes the approximations so bad. I also tried different learning_rates with the same results.

I also wanted to try to test the model by sending in the test data in batches. I tried this:

```
if i%500 == 0:

    rand_ind = np.random.randint(len(X_test),size=8)

    feed = {X_data:X_test[rand_ind],y_target:y_test[rand_ind]}

    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_target-y_output)) / 8

    print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict=feed))
```

but unfortunately I am always told that the index, which I chose with rand_ind it "not in index".

Answer (score 1):

You can try the tf.train.AdamOptimizer and increase your learning rate (maybe around 0.1). This will increase the convergence rate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is becoming even bigger as before

Comment: Sorry, the loss really gets lower, now around 860000 which is already an improvement. Are there maybe other mistakes in my code that keep me from getting better losses. I have to say that I am quite new to the topic and have especially problems with choosing the correct loss and optimizer functions. 
Would it maybe help to just check the loss on a smaller batch instead of the whole set? I tried to chose rows from the Dataframe with rand_ind = np.random.random_integers(len(X_test)+1) and feed = {X_data:X_test.iloc[rand_ind:rand_ind+8,:],y_target:y_test.iloc[rand_ind:rand_ind+8,:]}

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear to me. You may ask a different question in StackOverflow if its different from this one. btw if the loss is getting lower you can increase the learning rate further (1, 1.5 etc).